# scala connect hbase master failure

Tags: scala, api, hadoop, hbase

I write Scala code as below:

```
44 val config: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
 45     config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zooKeeperClientPort)
 46     config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zooKeeperQuorum)
 47     config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", zooKeeperZNodeParent)
 48     config.set("hbase.master", hbaseMaster)
 49     config.addResource("hbase-site.xml")
 50     config.addResource("hdfs-site.xml")
 51     HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
 52     val admin: HBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(config)
 53     // descriptor.addColumn(new HColumnDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("cfbfeature")))
 54     val conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
 55     table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf(outputTable))
```

here is my full error log:

> zooKeeperClientPort:2181, zooKeeperQuorum:zk1.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com,zk2.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com,zk3.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com,zooKeeperZNodeParent:/hbase, outputTable:RequestFeature, hbaseMaster:10.2.2.62:60000
>       16/12/13 08:25:56 WARN util.HeapMemorySizeUtil: hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit is deprecated by hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size
>       16/12/13 08:25:56 WARN util.HeapMemorySizeUtil: hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit is deprecated by hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size
>       16/12/13 08:25:56 WARN util.HeapMemorySizeUtil: hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit is deprecated by hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size
>       16/12/13 08:25:57 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x6ae9e162 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=zk2.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com:2181,zk1.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com:2181,zk3.hbase.busdev.usw2.cmcm.com:2181
>       16/12/13 08:25:57 WARN util.HeapMemorySizeUtil: hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit is deprecated by hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size
>       16/12/13 08:25:57 WARN util.DynamicClassLoader: Failed to identify the fs of dir hdfs://mycluster/hbase/lib, ignored
>       java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: mycluster
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.(Client.java:214)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1196)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1050)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:238)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:203)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.(ProtobufUtil.java:229)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:86)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:833)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(ConnectionManager.java:623)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2508)
>           at com.cmcm.datahero.streaming.actor.ToHBaseActor.preStart(ToHBaseActor.scala:51)
>           at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:472)
>           at com.cmcm.datahero.streaming.actor.ToHBaseActor.aroundPreStart(ToHBaseActor.scala:16)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       16/12/13 08:25:57 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x356c1ee7cac04c8

Comment: but the "mycluster" here is not a host. I am very confused about what's the error.
someone can help me?

Comment: you are connecting your cluster from windows or within cluster it self? hmaster ip  is correct?

Comment: also  check in the client program like this to verify correct jars in classpath `val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)`

Comment: thank you for all your help. I finally found my third-party scala-package version is incorrect. And i fixed it.

Comment: then please post it as answer and accept as owner. It will be pointer to others

Comment: ok. thank your for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally put hbase and hdfs xml confiure into sub path src/main/resources. Then addResouce to hadoop configure.
But that is not the core of my problem. The jar version of hbase package should match the hbase version. I fixed my build.sbt. The code posted below. Hopely could help someone meet the error I meet.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.4.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.0-cdh5.4.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0-cdh5.5.4"
// libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.0.0-CDH"
// libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.0.0"
// libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.0.0"

//scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main/scala"
//resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main/resources"
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
//unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "conf"
packAutoSettings
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
resolvers += "cloudera repo" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/"
resolvers += "cloudera repo1" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
```